# Thunderbird Certificate

Tags: certificate, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I'm actually developing an extension for Thunderbird. The main goal of it is to send mails to crm system.

I want to use web-service which at first wants certificate to connect. The correct certificate is installed at my PC so I want from my add-on to looking for correct certificate from bunch of installed certificates and trying to connect using everyone of them unlit it works.

After that directory to the correct cert should be saved. After looking for answer on the web I didn't find any example with functions dealing with certificates. However I found examples with md5 crypt.

Is it the only way to deal with it?